# what is the length of an array of struct?

Tags: solidity, truffle, struct

I made a Wallet Contract to store all the tokens an account possess.

There is a `mapping(address=>TokenInfo[])`, and `address` refers to the account, TokenInfo[] stored tokens which this account holds.
TokenInfo is an array of TokenInfo struct, in which `token` is the token address, `exist` means whether the token has been added to the array.

```
contract Wallet {
    struct TokenInfo {
        IERC20Token token;
        uint exist;//0 means unregistered
    }

    mapping(address=>TokenInfo[]) public tokenList;

    function Wallet() {

    }

    function addToken(address _account, IERC20Token _token) public {
        for (uint i = 0; i < tokenList[_account].length; i++) {//seems didn't enter the loop
            if (tokenList[_account][i].exist == 0) {
                var tokenInfo = TokenInfo(_token, 1);
                tokenList[_account].push(tokenInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    function getTokenListLength(address _account) public constant returns (uint) {
        return tokenList[_account].length;
    }
}
```

But when I call `addToken()` function, it didn't work.
It seems that it never entered the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The default value in a mapping for an array is an empty array.

In your case this means `tokenList[_account].length` is equal to 0.

And the loop will never be entered because the condition `i < tokenList[_account].length` becames `0 < 0` which is false.